Spring data Elasticsearch @query with projection/sourcefilter
I am using this documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/repositories/elasticsearch-repository-queries.html
I have a query like this:
interface BookRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Book, String> {
    @Query("""
        {
          "bool":{
            "must":[
              {
                "term":{
                  "name": "#{#name}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
        """)
    Page<Book> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}

Instead of Book, I want to get for example the author.
I want to use @Query and no programatical way of querying.
What I tried:

_source in the query -> which is an outdated approach so didnt work
@sourceFilter annotation -> didnt do anything
Interface-based Projections

Anyone know how I can set this up? Shouldn't be that hard, right?

do you want to use OR for fetching by book name or author?

You can try by combining custom method and elastic search query with source filtering.
public Page<AuthorProjectionTst> findAuthorsByName(String name, Pageable pageable) {
    NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
        .withQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", name))
        .withSourceFilter(new FetchSourceFilter(new String[]{"author"}, null))
        .withPageable(pageable)
        .build();

    return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, AuthorProjectionTst.class);
}

public interface AuthorProjectionTst { String getAuthor();}

You can call your custom method just like any other repository method:
 public void fetchAuthorsByName(String name) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
    Page<AuthorProjectionTst> authors = bookRepository.findAuthorsByName(name, pageable);
    authors.forEach(author -> {
        System.out.println(author.getAuthor());
    });
}

